# Error when creating token with JWT

Tags: php, api, jwt, token

I am building an API, but I get an Uncaught error when creating my token with JWT, when I run a post man call, I get in my error log Stack trace:

```
#0 [internal function]: Api->generateToken()
#1 /home/osconliz/public_html/Osconlizapicall/rest.php(42): ReflectionMethod->invoke(Object(Api))
#2 /home/osconliz/public_html/Osconlizapicall/index.php(4): Rest->processApi()
#3 {main}
thrown in /home/osconliz/public_html/Osconlizapicall/api.php on line 36
[19-May-2018 02:04:47 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'JWT' not found in /home/osconliz/public_html/Osconlizapicall/api.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Api->generateToken()
#1 /home/osconliz/public_html/Osconlizapicall/rest.php(42): ReflectionMethod->invoke(Object(Api))
#2 /home/osconliz/public_html/Osconlizapicall/index.php(4): Rest->processApi()
#3 {main}
```

but when I check my jwt file on my PHP server it has class JWT in it.

`**jwt.php**` page with class jwt screen shot

[image]

Then the page I am using to create the token which is `**api.php**`

//SECRETE_KEY is a constant for creating a pass for JWT

```
   <?php 
  class Api extends Rest {
    public $dbConn;  

     public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();  
        $db = new DbConnect;
        $this->dbConn = $db->connect();

    }

    public function generateToken(){
        $client_id_key = $this->validateParameter('client_id_key', $this->param['client_id_key'], STRING);
        //$client_secret_key = $this->validateParameter('client_secret_key', $this->param['client_secret_key'], STRING);
        //client_secret_key should be commented out it is not used for validation for security purposes, only id key

        $stmt = $this->dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `api_clients_properties` WHERE client_id = :client_id_key");
        $stmt->bindParam(":client_id_key", $client_id_key);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (!is_array($user)){
            $this->returnResponse(API_NAME_REQUIRED, "Invalid Client Id Key");
        }

        if ($user['property_status'] == "not verified"){
           $this->returnResponse(API_NAME_REQUIRED, "Property not verified, please contact admin, to verify it");   
        }

        $payload = [
           'iat' => time(),
           'iss' => 'localhost',
           'exp' => time() + (60),
           'userId' => $user['id']
        ];
        $token = JWT::encode($payload, SECRETE_KEY);
        echo $token;
    }

  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you copied the file from GitHub rather than using composer to install it, you will need to comment out the namespace lines at the top of the file. so from my snapshot at the very top of the first line of `jwt.php` screenshot, you will comment out `//namespace Firebase\JWT;` and you would not get the 500 internal server error again.

Comment: Don't do that, it could cause a naming conflict and break other things. You just need to use a proper autoloader. (Or `requice_once()` the right source files.)

Comment: Hy! I'm facing the same problem but can't solve it while commenting and also use auto `spl_autoload_register` but can't solve it.

Answer (score 2):

The `JWT` class is in the namespace `Firebase\JWT`, so you will either need to `use` it:

```
use \Firebase\Jwt\Jwt;
Jwt::encode(...);
```

Or use its full namespace when invoking:

```
\Firebase\Jwt\Jwt::encode();
```

Comment: thanks but it did not solve the issue, I post the answer below.